# Plotar grafico de uma expressão algébrica em python

Tags: python, sympy

estou tentando plotar um grafico de uma integral que resolvi, mas está dando erro :

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import *
%matplotlib inline

r=Symbol('r')
e=Symbol('e')
r=(1,10,100)

k=((rho)/(E*r**2))*(-e**(-r)*r**(2)-2e**(-r)*r-2e**(-r)+2)
k(r)
plot.title('comportamento do campo')
plot.xlabel('raio da esfera')
plot.ylabel('campo eletrico')
plot(r,k(r))
```

o erro que dá é:

```
 File "<ipython-input-65-70ed324ef8d6>", line 1
    k=((rho)/(E*r**2))*(-e**(-r)*r**(2)-2e**(-r)*r-2e**(-r)+2)
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Erro clássico, Operador ^ = XOR = Sets each bit to 1 if only one of two bits is 1, você não está trabalhando com bits, porque está usando esse operador? O erro em seguida é consequencia desse ai.

Comment: Camila, o seu `e` é a constante de Euler? e eu acho que você deveria usar o plot específico do `sympy`pra plotar o seu gráfico, uma vez que a expressão é analítica. de resto, a sua expressão tá usando o `^` em vez do `**` para potência, então a expressão correta seria `k = (r/E*r**2)*-np.e**-r*r**2*-2*np.e**-r*r-2*np.e**-r+2`

o gráfico ainda vai ter alguns problemas pra plotar, mas consigo te ajudar se você der mais detalhes dessas variáveis

Comment: Eu resolvi uma integral, po/Er^2 integral de r^2.e^-r, ai o resultado deu essa expressão q coloquei, queria plotar o grafico dela

Comment: editei o codigo para as modificações q fiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não ficou inteiramente claro para mim sua expressão. Fiz algumas hipóteses na implementação abaixo que, creio, não comprometem o exemplo.

Em primeiro lugar, se `e` é a constante de Euller, o ideal é você utilizar a função `exp` nativa do sympy. Em segundo lugar, é preciso explicitar o operador `*` em todas as multiplicações. O programa não estava entendendo expressões como `2e`, por exemplo. Para esse caso o correto seria `2*e`.

Não está claro se você quer plotar uma função univariada. Se este for o caso, você precisa atribuir valores para `E` e `pho`. Essa última variável não foi declarada e então substitui ela pelo símbolo `p`:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import plot
from sympy.abc import p,E #note que as importações de símbolos podem ser feitas todas de uma vez

k=((p)/(E*r**2))*(-exp(-r)*r**(2)-2*exp(-r)*r-2*exp(-r)+2)
k
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que eu alterei as importações e não defini o intervalo desejado de `r`, isso deve ser feito apenas na hora de plotar o gráfico.

Fazendo as substituições das constantes, temos:

```
p1=plot(k.subs({E:10,p:15}), (r,1,100), 
        title='comportamento do campo', xlabel='raio da esfera',
        ylabel='campo eletrico')
p1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: é isso mesmo muito obrigada

Comment: Ok! Se a resposta te atendeu, marque a questão como resolvida. É a prática do site e eu ganho uns pontos tbm rs

Comment: como eu marco como resolvida? sou nova no site, não estou encontrando

Comment: tem um V de baixo da contagem de pontos da minha resposta. Veja esse exemplo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png